# Unable to set breakpoint in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html

I have written a simple javaScript function to validate required userName field using JS for my learning purposes.

I am facing two issues -

1. In submit button, onclick event handler does not invoke
   `checkRequired` method, and form is posted back.
2. I am not able to set breakpoint in chrome debugger.
3. Even using debugger exclusively in code does not bring the control
   to debugger breakpoint.

**TaskManager.js**

```
function checkRequired() {
    debugger;
    var userName = document.getElementById("txtUserName");
    if (userName.length == 0) {
        alert("username is required attribute");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**AddNewUser:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Add new User</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="all">
        button {
            width: 65px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="TaskManager.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="AddNewUser.html" style="width: 560px; height: 850px; margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 10px">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>New User</legend>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label>User Name:</label></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="txtUserName" name="User Name" maxlength="10" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <button id="btnSubmit" type="submit" onclick="checkRequired()">Add User</button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button id="btnCancel">Cancel</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </fieldset>

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for any help to resolve the issue.

Comment: Did you check the console for errors?

Comment: yes I do not see any error, in console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your breakpoint is not reached then the function is somehow not accessible and you should get an error in the console. Is the function in the global scope?

[Here's your code](http://jsfiddle.net/uksnU/3/), to which I made a couple of changes to let it work.
First of all the result of your handler has to be taken into account:

```
<button id="btnSubmit" type="submit" onclick="javaScript:return checkRequired();">
```

Then you have to check against `.value.length` inside the textbox you're trying to validate:

```
var userName = document.getElementById("txtUserName");
if (userName.value.length === 0) {[...]
```

Anyway I would advise you to use an unobtrusive approach if possible, and bind the event directly in your javascript code, instead of defining it in the markup:

```
var submitBtn = document.getElementById("btnSubmit");
submitBtn.onclick = function checkRequired() {
    console.log('aho');
    var userName = document.getElementById("txtUserName");
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the script file is being loaded. Put an alert at the top of the file outside the function definition.

If the alert does not display check carefully the name of your script file. Is it the same as referenced in the script tag? Is it in the same directory?